# How to make Mongoid order properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I've been trying to figure out why Mongoid thinks 387 is smaller than 67. I have two records and the row with 67 is appearing above the row with 387 every time. My query is simple

```
Building.desc(:violations)
```

I have also tried `order_by()` and it's the same story.

Edit:

I now changed the field type to Integer on some fields, and to BigDecimal for other fields where the numbers are greater -- especially currency figures. That fixed the Integer fields, but BigDecimal fields are still not sorting properly.

Comment: Is the comparison based on text/alphanumeric strings, or on numeric values?  If the values are stored as strings, then comparison is invariably done lexicographically and 387 _is_ smaller than 67 since 3 comes before 6.

Comment: @hardmath yes, you are right. I believe it was related to field typing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the data type on the fields.  In MongoDB, it can be pretty easy to store something as a string when you really meant to store it as a numeric value of some sort.

More information and examples about data types available from the [MongoDB documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/BSON).

Comment: I didn't specify a field type originally. So I think you are right. It's easy to add field type into the model, but do you know how to change the field type of values already added to the database?

Comment: I now changed the field type to Integer on some fields, and to
BigDecimal for other fields where the numbers are greater --
especially currency figures. That fixed the Integer fields, but
BigDecimal fields are still not sorting properly.

Comment: Hm..Integer is not sorting properly either. Weird.

Comment: Ah. My mistake. It was a typo. Working now. Thanks, Andy!